# How to add a UILabel inside a UIScrollView programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel

Ok i have already gone through similar questions, but none of them helped.
I want to add a UILabel inside a UIScrollView so that the Label can be scrolled if the contents are large. Here is my code:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *myLabel;
    UIScrollView *myScroll;
}
```

ViewController.h:

```
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+30, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+30, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

myLabel.text = @"Large random text";
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[myLabel sizeToFit];

myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width,         
myLabel.frame.size.height);
[myScroll addSubview:myLabel];

[self.view addSubview:myScroll];
```

I searched a lot on the internet but could not find a answer, can someone let me know what the issue is ?
Thank You !

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: Keep in mind that the label's frame needs to be relative to the scroll view, not `self.view`.

Comment: @rmaddy - there is not scroll bar, so i can't view the entire text.

Comment: @rmaddy - Thank you, that did the trick, the label has to be relative to the Scroll view, add that to your answer so that i will have it accepted :)

Comment: As requested, I updated my answer with the info about the label's frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you need to size the label as needed so it is big enough for the given text. Then add the label to scroll view. Then set the scroll view's `contentSize` so it fits the whole label. This will ensure the scroll view allows you to scroll to see the whole label.

In addition to this, make sure the label's frame is relative to the scroll view and not to `self.view`. In other words, setting the label's frame's origin to 0,0 will put the label in the top left corner of the scroll view regardless of the position of the scroll view relative to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do that, but I would like to suggest an alternative that may suit your needs. Use a UITextView, but set " [textView userInteractionEnabled:NO] " and it will act as a label, since it cannot be edited. It might end up looking like how you want.

Comment: absolutely the simplest solution!  I didn't even bother setting user interaction programatically, just did the whole thing in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing your contentSize like below code,

```
myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height + 100);
```

Hope it will work for u.

Comment: Actually u are getting less height then self.view's height so scrollview won't scroll. To make it scroll, u must have to give greater height then its actual height. Thats it.

Comment: @Tejas K -  if u will give your label height in scrollview.contentSize then it won't work bcz its height is less then actual height of scrollview. you can simply check like, myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 750)

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to use View(ContentView) to place the labels.

2.Add the ContentView into ScrollVIew.

3.Assign the ContentView Size whatever You Want

Go Through This Link,You Will get a Clear idea.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI

Remove scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init]; this is not necessary.Please Upvote if it helps.